# How can I remove row from table without removing data from data source?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using a server side table for displaying records.  Within each table row there is an "Exclude" button.  Once a user clicks that button i would like to remove that row from the table.  However, i do not want to remove that data from the data source.  Is it possible to remove a row client side without making a call to the server side function?  Currently, this will hit the server side function and reload the same data, including the excluded record:

```
table.row(rowIndex).remove().draw();
```

Comment: Notice how I revised your post title to be a coherent sentence? That's what's expected of you here. Please see [ask].

Comment: Best way I can think of is to set up a table that stores the excluded rows per user and just filters the results before rendering it in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a data attribute to the button containing the id.  I pass this id to the server side function and remove the record with that id before returning the results.